# sending error message in json using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am validating input fields in ruby on rails. I checking whether user have entered or filled these fields or not. If lets say `name` field is not filled then send an error message to user with indication that `name` field is not filled. Same goes with other errors. How can I send this kind of message in json using ruby on rails.

Here is what I am doing right now.

this model

```
validates :email, :name, :company, :presence => true
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z/
```

Here is how I am currently sending json data to client

```
@contacts = Contact.new(params[:contact])

if @contacts.save
  render :json => { :error => 0, :success => 1 }
else
  render :json => { :error => 1, :success => 0 }
end
```

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way would be to send down a hash of the errors.

so:

```
render :json => { :errors => @contacts.errors.as_json }, :status => 420
```

note that `:status => 420` is required to make things like jquery's $.ajax method call their error callback and you should never return a 200 status (the default) when there is an error.

Comment: This should really be HTTP 422, as 420 is not part of the standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#420)

Answer (score 1):

You really should use http status codes to tell the user what is going on, so for invalid record there is

```
420 Invalid Record  Record could not be saved
```

And then in your JSON return you could also have an error message that would return your active record / active model error messages in it to give them more information.

Comment: This should really be HTTP 422, as 420 is not part of the standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#420)